# Strange whitespace after body tag

Tags: css

Take a look please at the bottom of the site http://nurmura.kz just after the blue line there's a white space i have noticed in firefox 18 that blue line should be sticked to the bottom of the window, in google chrome i can't see that. Any suggestions on how to get rid of that white space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clear your **#footer-bottom**. Write like this:

```
#footer-bottom {
    height: 53px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 40px;
    width: 940px;
}
```